# Solr pagination problem when grouping results

Tags: solr, websolr, solritas

I use **Solr 3.3** and **Solritas UI** . I have applied **result grouping by default**. 
When I search with some keyword I don't get the results across multiple pages.Even I provide empty query and search I dont get results spanned across multiple pages. I think this problem is related to pagination and I guess I need to change the velocity scripts.

Please guide me on this...

Edit :

Under browse.vm this is the code that is related to pagination and when the results are grouped we dont have link to next page macro being called.

Can some one give some clear picture for my vague idea.

Right now what ever I search I just get **1 group(s) found** in some ms.

```
  #if($response.response.get('grouped'))
  $response.response.get('grouped').size() group(s) found in ${response.responseHeader.QTime} ms 
  #else$page.results_found results found in ${response.responseHeader.QTime} ms
  Page $page.current_page_number of $page.page_count#end



  #if($response.response.get('grouped'))
  #else
  #link_to_previous_page("previous")
  $page.results_found results found.
  Page $page.current_page_number of $page.page_count
  #link_to_next_page("next")
  #end
```

Answer (score 0):

How many "NumFound" do you have for your group ? Are you sure the field you are grouping on does not have a unique value or is empty, and you get all your results in one group ?

EDIT: Do you get something like this with only one group (what I am saying is maybe your groupValue is unique ??) ?

[image]

Comment: The numFound depends upon the term I search . I get values ranging from 240 to 300. The field is not empty. The problem here is not with the values but with pagination when the results are grouped . I guess I need to implement my own macro when the results are grouped. Somethin like #link_to_next_group and #link_to_previous_group.

Comment: I get only one group because I group based on only one field (name) To increase the group value I need to group by more than one field. Reg groupValues I have different groupValues returned in the response. See the problem here is pagination is not implemented when grouping is enabled. I need a way to get the current page value and total pageCount when grouping is enabled. I need to implement this as a macro in VM_global_library.vm as mentioned in the above comment